# How can I program ksh93 to use bash autocompletion?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, ksh

In a [comment in response to a shell question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933445/a-better-linux-shell/933489#933489), user [tinkertim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tinkertim) said that it was easy to hack `ksh` to use the `bash` autocompletion library.  I would like nothing better than to use `bash` autocompletion with AT&T `ksh93`.  How can this be done?

`ksh93` has a new release several times a year, so I am looking for a solution that does not involve modifying the source code.  `ksh93` can link new C modules dynamically and also is highly programmable (I run a ksh function at every keystroke), so modifying the source should not really be necessary.

**Note:** I am not talking about *filename* autocompletion, which is easy to do in `ksh`.  I'm talking about all the other yummy autocompletion stuff that bash does, like autocompletion options for `nmh` commands or autocompleting Mercurial commmands.  Stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is the Readline wrapper, rlwrap. Maybe you already have a software package for your system.

It sits above the standard input of a program you start, it's configurable and a bit programmable, it keeps a history.

I usually use it for stuff like Oracle SQL*Plus.

It may or may not be the tool you're searching for, you have to check.

Comment: rlwrap actually looks quite useful for other problems, but its autocompletion facilities are minimal.

Comment: And it would collide with the input capabilities of KSH anyways, if there are some specials.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the simplest ways I have found to do this (on a client's server where I have no access to change packages and whatnot) is to set the line editor to emacs `set -o emacs` then double-tap ESC (ESC-ESC).

This isn't the most effective auto-completion, but it's all I have here without doing some funky hacking of my .profile and possibly violate usage rules.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `set -o emacs` there is also `set -o vi` which activates the keyboard combo ESC-\ for filename completion.  (The ESC enters command mode, the \ engages autocomplete to complete as much of the filename as it can.)  `set -o vi` also of course enables your command line for vi-style editing with its two modes of command-mode and insert-mode.

I concede this doesn't answer your original question of emulating bash-style autocompletion in ksh, but at least you are aware if you were not before aware of another way to engage ksh's build in autocomplete.

I also noticed another thread here with some related ksh autocomplete information, including ESC-= to get list of choices: [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015631/tab-complete-with-ksh-in-emacs-mode-without-bindings)

Comment: *Filename* autocompletion is no problem in ksh.  It's all the other autocompletion stuff I'd like, such as the ability to autocomplete `cvs` commands and suchlike.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the tab key to call a bash script which uses the `complete` builtin, so hitting tab in ksh93 actually runs bash to complete the text.

Consult
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins
and
http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html (look for "Key Bindings") for details

Answer (score -1):

Try hitting ESC then '\' key. It should mimic the bash's autocomplete feature.