# Tab complete with KSH in Emacs mode without bindings

Tags: unix, emacs, ksh

I'm trying to enable auto complete for the command line in emacs mode.  When I try:

```
set -o emacs
bind '^I'=complete
bind '^I'=complete-list
```

and relog on, I get "bind command not found" error.

Is there any other way to tab-autocomplete in emacs mode, i.e. a tab completes to the first difference?  If not, how do I install bindings in ksh?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bind` is Bash/readline-specific.

From the [ksh faq](http://kornshell.com/doc/faq.html),

```
Q6.     Does ksh support file name completion?
A6.     Yes, it does.  The default key binding is <ESC><ESC>
        however, starting with the 'g' point release, <TAB> also works
        for completion.  Note, the vi users need to set -o viraw
        in order to get <TAB> completion to work.
```

`ksh93g` was released in 1994-04-30, so I'm quite surprised if it doesn't work for you... what's your `ksh` version?

Comment: version M-11/16/88i
Thanks for your response.  Is there also any way to display possible completion options under the command, i.e, if you hit esc esc and you reach a branching point, to see what your options are to make a decision?

Comment: To see the possible options, the default key binding is <ESC>=.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, key binding was introduced in ksh93,

> Q5.   What are the major new features of KornShell 1993? 
>   A5.   The only major new interactive feature is key binding. ...
>   ([KSH-93 FAQ](http://kornshell.com/doc/faq.html))

In emacs mode, hitting

```
<ESC>=
```

gives you a list that matches the text you have typed up to that point.