# Tab complete second command

Tags: ksh

I am trying to get tab completion on the second atom of a command.

I.e. `man do<tab complete>`

In bash this can be done with `complete -cf <command>` but I am not sure if this is possible in ksh. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which `ksh` flavour you are using.

In AT&T `ksh88` as well as `pdksh` and derivatives (`mksh`, NetBSD `ksh`, OpenBSD `ksh` / `oksh`), this is not possible (asides from [really weird hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16818888/2171120). They (I can say that for guaranteed for `mksh` as I am its developer) complete the second (and follow-up, except after a closing parenthesis `)`) word of a command consistently as cwd-relative pathname (“file” simplified).

AT&T `ksh93` in the last version from AT&T `93u+20120801` does not have programmable tab completion; however, the new development under `situ` from Red Hat introduced it, as indicated [in the manpage](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/d2044373cf93f8f45bfd04d995697837f55a63ba/src/cmd/ksh93/ksh.1#L5631). You will not likely find this in any stable distro yet, however, they have recently issued their first stable post-fork release.